# How to import list of blob values (images) and ids from mysql database to excel file

Tags: php, mysql, excel

How can I import a list of blob values (images) and ids from mysql database to an excel file?

I am trying to import a list of records from a database table in mysql - say, import an employee record - along with the blob value for their image, and export it to a excel sheet. Please update me if you have a solution.

Comment: What you have already done, and where is the error or something ?

Comment: We can help you to correct a mistake in the code, but we dont give you the whole code.

Comment: Where is your problem? Can't you read the data from MySQL? Have you looked at any of the libraries available for writing Excel files from PHP?